# Solving for $d$, given $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 519 = d + 36\sqrt{10a+14b+22c-d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need hints in solving this.

> Determine $d$, given that the real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ satisfy the equation below.
>   $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 519 = d + 36\sqrt{10a+14b+22c-d}$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Zfv.png))

I don't think I've solved anything of its sort before. I tried Cauchy-Schwarz which seemed promising at first but got stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why diophantine?  It says real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta=a^2+b^2+c^2+519$ and $\xi=10a+14b+22c$, you have:
$$\zeta-d=36\sqrt{\xi-d}$$
This is very easy to solve because, you have to impose:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\zeta-d\geq0
\\ \xi-d\geq0
\\ (\zeta-d)^2=36(\xi-d)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
In particular you are interested to the last equation:
$$\zeta^2+d^2-2\zeta d=36^2\xi -36^2d$$
And so:
$$d^2(36^2+1)-2\zeta d +\zeta^2-36\xi^2=0\leftrightarrow d=\frac{2\zeta\pm\sqrt{4\zeta^2-4(36^2+1)(\zeta^2-36\xi^2)}}{2(36^2+1)}=\frac{2\zeta\pm\sqrt{186768\xi^2-5184\zeta^2}}{2(36^2+1)}$$

Comment: @Arannya Monzur: if this ha been useful, maybe a favourite answer?

Comment: of course, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: put the $d$ on the left side, square both sides, then complete the square in $a,b,c$.